# Changing layout of defaul gallery output to masonry

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I'm changing the default layout for gallery shortcode. I have this in my functions.php:

```
$attr['columns'] = 1;
$attr['size'] = 'full';
$attr['link'] = 'none';

$attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
$attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
```

These are hardcoded default options, which allow me to set max-width to all images whithin the .gallery:

```
$.each($('.gallery img'), function () {
    $(this).css({
        'max-width' : 300
    });
});
```

After that I'm running masonry and it looks almost perfect. **My problem is...** that I want to set random max-width in one of the following ways:

1) randomly set max-width to each image from an array with three or four values

2) generate random even number withing a range (say 260 to 480 with a 20px "step") and set it as max-width

**...and I have no clue how to achieve that**. It's been dozens of google search queries and still I'm floating in nowhere. I've tried simple javascript math.floor and math.random function, but I'm not a programmer, I guess I'm doing something wrong. I want to make galleries mobile-friendly.

Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this:

```
$.each($('.gallery img'), function () {
  var rndmnum = Math.floor((Math.random()*11)+1);
  rndmnum = rndmnum *20 + 260;

  $(this).css({
     'max-width' : rndmnum
  });
});
```

note: untested

sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904707/javascript-random-number-between-15-and-225-increments-of-30
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733838/random-max-width-for-each-image-on-a-page

edit: corrected calculation